# New BFC "clearing" floating boxes

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

As the example shows, applying `display: inline-block;` to the containing block seems to "clear" the floating box within.

```css
.wrapper-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-column {
  background-color: teal;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-inline-block">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  <p>Non-float</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  <p>Non-float</p>
</div>
```

I have no idea how this happens. All what I know is that `display: inline-block;` creates a new block formatting context.

My question is: how does the new BFC "clear" floating boxes within?

---

Followup question:

Curiously, when I change `<p>Non-float</p>` to `Non-float`, the "clearing" effect disappears. It would be nice if someone can explain the reason behind to me.

```css
.wrapper-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-column {
  background-color: teal;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-inline-block">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  Non-float
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  Non-float
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because inline-blocks with the default `width: auto` are sized according to the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm. CSS2.1 does not fully define how that algorithm should handle floating contents, but it seems browsers do this:

1. The inline-block is sized ignoring floats
2. The line boxes inside the inline-block are as wide as the inline-block
3. The float shrinks the line boxes
4. Therefore, the non-floating contents no longer fit in the shrunk space, so the wrap to the next line.

Note there is no clearing, if you make the inline-block wide enough, the text will appear next to the float.

```css
.wrapper.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.w400 {
  width: 400px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.left-column {
  background-color: teal;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Shrink-to-fit inline-block:</p>
<div class="wrapper inline-block">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  <p>Non-float</p>
</div>
<p>Explicit width inline-block:</p>
<div class="wrapper inline-blockw w400">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  <p>Non-float</p>
</div>
<p>Fill-available block:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <p>Float</p>
  </div>
  <p>Non-float</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! I've added a "followup question" in the OP, could you also answer that? While it's usually not appreciate to ask new questions by editing, I think in this case, it can make my post more complete.

Comment: @sunqingyao It's a bit hand-waving because as I said CSS2.1 does not fully define how shrink-to-fit should handle inner floats. My guess is that the size is calculated before the float has been moved next to the following block, but after it has been moved next to the following inline-block. It doesn't make much sense because since a float is block-level, an anonymous block box should wrap the text, just like a `<p>`. So the behavior should be the same, unless floats are not considered block-level when [controlling box generation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#box-gen).