# Extra text raising containing box

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, clearfix

It's just weird:

- When there is only some text, `.main` is pushed down. (The reason is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39945774/5399734).)
- When there is lots of text, the first few words of `.main` appears between two floating boxes.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.left-column {
  float: left;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    L Float
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    R Float
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    some text
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    L Float
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    R Float
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    a huge amount of text
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to know why extra text can move `.main` upwards.

Comment: because a **huge amount of text** has a [x] width. and left or right Float Content put this line and warp text to next line.......you just set style for .main { clear:both }

Comment: @MrLogical So the width of `.main` is determined *before* the text it contains is put into the normal flow and rendered?

Comment: yes . what this > left or right Content ... ?  use the absolute position and relative parent position for this....